# xamarin forms app not builded when uncheck the "Use Shared Runtime" in release mode using xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using xamarin forms.
My android App is Builded successfully only when i check the "Use Shared Runtime" in release mode. When i uncheck "Use Shared Runtime", then error show like "The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly", while Build the project.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use Shared Runtime in release mode, you have to package mono into your app package. Shared Runtime is for Debug only to speed up deployment process during development. It installs Mono runtime before deploying your app then. That is not possible when distributing via App Stores.